# Can you change the type of an object in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I created a rectangle object with text inside an EXCEL document and formatted it a lot, if I want to suddenly change it to circular (oblique) type, is there a way to do this in EXCEL?

Right now, I would create an circular (oblique) object then copy the format of the object via the copy format icon. As for the dimension of the object, I would just manually copy it. Also the text written inside the object are also manually copied. I was hoping if there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with VBA Macro's. Admitedly I tried with Excel 2013 so things might be slightly different with 2010.

```
Selection.ShapeRange.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval
```

Changes the selected shape to Oval

```
Selection.ShapeRange.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle
```

changes it back.

You can also set height, width, etc. as in this example:

```
Sub Macro3()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 3")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 53.8582677165
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.11, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval
End Sub
```

The above selects a specific shape. You could get VBA to find all of the shapes. `ActiveSheet.Shapes` will return a range that you can loop over, check the current `AutoShapeType` and change it if needed.